# Tegelbergbahn Tickets

Tags: tickets, price, architecture

I'll be visiting the Neuschwanstein Castle later this year, and I'd like to take a ride on this tegelbergbahn toboggan close to the castle:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O-e_F0wodyk

On their website I found only the opening hours and prices:
https://www.tegelbergbahn.de/oeffnungszeiten.html
https://www.tegelbergbahn.de/preise/sommerrodelbahn.html

Is it possible to buy tickets in advance to avoid lines and setbacks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually most rides don't provide tickets in advance.
On the website of Tegelbergbahn there was no indication that you can buy tickets in advance.
Nevertheless you could call them and ask.